# PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/mnt/web112/c3/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-includes/random_c

Tags: php, wordpress

I'll be honest, I have very little programming experience..
Some person offered me to make a website for my mom's dog grooming website and it all went good for a year or so and just recently the page doesnt do what is was supposed to do. I've tried to reload to a backup that my hosting generates from time to time, I guess. SO I've made it to a logfile and this came up;

> 24.05.2018 17:18:39 kluifje.info [client 143.179.63.0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/mnt/web112/c3/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php' (include_path='.:/opt/RZphp56/includes') in /mnt/web112/c3/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-includes/compat.php on line 435

This is the last line of the log, where it all started with, after I tried to load a backup it gave me this

> 24.05.2018 12:43:27 kluifje.info [client 212.78.74.0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/mnt/web112/c3/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php' (include_path='.:/opt/RZphp56/includes') in /mnt/web112/c3/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-includes/compat.php on line 435
>   24.05.2018 12:48:33 kluifje.info [client 212.78.74.0] AH01215: PHP Warning:  require(/mnt/web112/c3/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/web112/c3/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-includes/compat.php on line 435: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/49/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-login.php
>   24.05.2018 12:48:33 kluifje.info [client 212.78.74.0] AH01215: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/mnt/web112/c3/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php' (include_path='.:/opt/RZphp56/includes') in /mnt/web112/c3/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-includes/compat.php on line 435: /home/strato/http/premium/rid/49/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-login.php

But I switched back to the most recent backup, so I guess the first blockquote should be back .

Can anyone please help me figure this out? My mom's kinda f*cked because she's losing customers. Might find a decent loyal person to maintain her page..

I am familiar with ftp clients so I should be able to download the files and put them back in if needed.

Comment: take a fresh copy of wordpress and overwrite the wp-admin and wp-include folders. It seems something has gone wrong on your installation

Comment: 1. Did you make sure the file is there? *'/mnt/web112/c3/44/58344944/htdocs/WordPress_SecureMode_01/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php'* 2. Did you make sure the permissions are appropriate? `ls -l` if you are connected via SSH

Comment: This doesn't give me a clean WP?

Comment: `WordPress_SecureMode_01` what is this folder?

Comment: I did not make the site so I dont really know what happened. There hasnt been made any changes. Im installing filezilla now to see into it

Comment: On my hosting I see theres a redirection to /WordPress_SecureMode_01

Comment: @Janneau if I helped to answer your question, could you accept my answer, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your hosting provider updated your wordpress install. This will happen from time to time (depending on hosting service). Were there any modifications (customizations) to the original wordpress site?

This error is specifically telling you that there is a missing file, that is required by the application to run, and that the loader cannot find it.

In php, there are 2 different ways to include files, requires (require, require_once) and includes (include, include_once). These tell your application to look here, and bring the contents of this page into the current runtime.

Require is different than includes because if the required file cannot be found, it will crash your application, as you see in your logs.

Check out this link on [requires](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).

Here is the file that your system is trying to locate on github [random.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/random_compat/random.php).

My best guess is that was probably there was an update by your hosting provider that was corrupted for some reason. You can probably work with them to re-install your application.

Comment: Okay I'll see into that. I also noticed that my SSL licence was expired. Could that have anything to do with it? (my best guess since i noticed theres a 'secure' part in it) I've requested a new ssl but its still pending.. I don't know if there has been any modifications to the wordpress original code. I can reload a backup but my hosting requires an extra database for this action. So I need to upgrade it to reload a WP backup.

Comment: Im browsing through the files and there is no map named random-compat, nor a file named random.php

Comment: I did a little digging and found some similar issues with other wordpress sites. It is probably because of an update gone wrong. I found some steps [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-in-wp-settings-preventing-site-access/) that should probably help. Look at the last post made. The user explains how they fixed the issue. It looks like you'll have to re-upload some files.

Comment: I still have some of the wp-includes and the wp-admin. But someway my wp-content is missing on my hosting. After some research I now assume that the site's content is completely gone?

Comment: No @Janneau, **ALL** of your actual content is there. Wordpress stores the actual content in the database. The directories your looking at is merely the directory structure of the application. This is what makes your site run. If you're missing wp-includes, admin, replace the files that are missing. It should be that easy. If you're nervous about messing with them, talk to your hosting provider, they should be able to help you restore your site. Let me know how it went.

Comment: I'm going to look at my downloaded WP folder and replace everything I need. I'll skip all the files if they're already there and see how it goes. I'll get back at you. Thanks so much.